# How to export AWS Keyspaces tables from one AWS account to another in a different AWS region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, disaster-recovery, amazon-keyspaces

As cross-account, cross region replication is not yet available for AWS Keyspaces, what can we do to kinda support this usecase?

I am thinking about either using an active-active topology between 2 regions / 2 accounts fed by a single stream, but it implies lots of infra changes as well it would increase possible ops cost.

A one shot thing would be to generate table dump through cqlsh in S3 and import them on a brand new AWS Keyspaces.

Anyone has already done this kind of operation on AWS Keyspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyspaces [now supports](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/announcing-amazon-keyspaces-multi-region-replication/) multi-region replication for active active topologies.
Create a multi region keyspaces using the following example

```
 CREATE  KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS aws_global
WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
                    'us-east-2' : 3 , 'us-west-2' : 3 }
AND TAGS = {'blog':'keyspaces', 'launch':'multi-Region'};
```

For import and export, My favorite approach is to use AWS Glue and the Spark Cassandra connector. You can find scripts for import and export [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-examples/tree/main/scala/datastax-v4/aws-glue). Using Glue you export to S3, replicate the bucket to another region and perform import from s3.

Comment: Thanks! I will check if multi region replication can cover most of our cases. Using S3 with cross-region / cross-account replication is another way for specific cases. I see most examples are in scala, it would be great that these scripts would also available in python, I feel less people use Scala nowadays and prefer not introducing new language in projects.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much data you're talking about, but you could always try a nightly run using the [DSBulk](https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk) tool.  Run an [unload](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkSimpleUnload.html) from the source region, and then run a [load](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkSimpleLoad.html) operation to the destination region.